# Font Identification help for DiffChecker logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need help identifying a font. I've tried WhatsThisFont with no luck. I appreciate any help. I'm specially interested in the "Diff" part, although both would be helpful.

[image]

(this is the current logo of [DiffChecker.com](http://www.DiffChecker.com))

Also, it doesn't have to be the *exact* same one... I like the look and a similar font would also work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: DIFF part, I am pretty sure is a vector graphic

Comment: I'm with Stanley VM on this one, probably not a font at all since there are gradients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Diff" is probably inspired (and adjusted by hand) by one of the variations of

[TT COCON](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-cocon/) -

[image]

The checker is out of interest - could be easily find as Vito Compressed Bold/Dense Bold/ or multiple others with similar appearance.